# MS Access 2010, How to open to a new form with fields pre-populated based on a different form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two linked tables with their corresponding forms: contracts and activities. A given contract can have several activities. I would like to have a function that allows me to open the activities form to a new record from the contract form such that the contract number AND output number is pre-populated.

I've tried where arguments on the open form cmd, but that doesn't apply for new records.

I tried to follow this thread

"[access 2010 form new record pre filled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557746/access-2010-form-new-record-pre-filled-button)"

but I'm new to access and didn't understand the code.

Thanks!

Comment: `I've tried where arguments on the open form cmd, but that doesn't apply for new records.` Did you save the `Contract Form` first?

Comment: This is not true: "...arguments on the open form cmd, but that doesn't apply for new records."

Comment: personally, I would leave the key fields on your parent form and exclude them from the child (activity) subform, as you don't want them modified.

Comment: @random_answer_guy Yeah, I imagine this kind of code will have to be in the after update section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxuIS2JuH4k

Granted this uses Macros, but it works. It is easy with a command button as opposed to an after update event. I have found this to be preferable anyways since otherwise I risk created a lot of duplicate data.

Best,